# Flutter Drawer Animation Curve

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-scaffold

Is there a way to add a curve to a flutter scaffold drawer? For example Curves.ElasticOut.

I thought about extending the Drawer or DrawerControllerState class to create a custom version that allows a curve input however there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this.

There is a useful plugin that gives curve functionality using its own sidemenu class but I would like to do this using the scaffold drawer as it doesn't seem like it should be a difficult extension
(alternative plugin https://github.com/GabrieleCicconetti/uts_sidemenu/blob/master/lib/uts_sidemenu.dart)

I have researched existing SO questions and cannot find one duplicating this topic however this is my first time question on Stack Overflow so apologies if I have made any errors here.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried more about what you wanna do, but of course i couldn't do it.
But i have create custom drawer with something different animation. here you can give your `duration`, `curve`.
So is it more complex and beautiful drawer than you wanna create.
Here is source code and expains:

First we need to create two Stateful widget, `CustomDrawer` and `HomeScreem`:
After creating this widgets, we need to create `Wrapper` widget which one will controle our screen changes.

- **`Wrapper` widget:**

```dart
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        CustomDrawer(),
        HomeScreen(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And then we have to create our `CustomDrawer` widget:

- **`CustomDrawer` widget:**

```dart
class CustomDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomDrawerState createState() => _CustomDrawerState();
}

class _CustomDrawerState extends State<CustomDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffD53437),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          /// Add here whatever you want..
          Row(children: []),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Alright time to create `HomeScreen` widget which one will manage animations. so everthing we have to do is here.
Here we need to Create a Stateful wideget and return `AnimatedContainer`. as you can see:

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      color: Colors.grey[900],
      child: buildScaffold(),
    );
  }

  Widget buildScaffold() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildCustomAppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Curve Drawer Example"),
      )
    );
  }
```

And now we gonna make methods and some calculatings for manage our screen.
First create this variables on down to `_HomeScreenState`:

```dart
double x = 0;
double y = 0;
double s = 1;
bool _isDrawerOpened = false;
int _currentIndex = 0;
```

Then we need two method, `openDrawer` and `closeDrawer`.

- **First is `openDrawer`:**

```dart
void openDrawer() {
  setState(() {
    x = 250;
    y = 150;
    s = 0.6;
    _isDrawerOpened = true;
  });
}
```

- **Second is `closeDrawer`:**

```dart
void closeDrawer() {
  setState(() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    s = 1;
    _isDrawerOpened = false;
  });
}
```

And time to fill our `AnimatedContainer` for do changes:

- **Our `AnimatedContainer` after filling:**

```dart
AnimatedContainer(
  color: Colors.grey[900],
  curve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(x, y, 0)..scale(s),
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  child: buildScaffold(),
);
```

And now we need appBar to use our methods, so for `openDrawer` and `closeDrawer`:

```dart
AppBar buildCustomAppBar() {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        _isDrawerOpened ? Icons.clear : Icons.menu,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: _isDrawerOpened ? closeDrawer : openDrawer,
    ),
  );
}
```

If you was complete this steps then you can use and enjoy! just give `Wrapper` in to your main.dart > MaterialApp's home.

- **Full Code of `HomeScreen`:**

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final pageController = PageController();

  double x = 0;
  double y = 0;
  double s = 1;
  bool _isDrawerOpened = false;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  void openDrawer() {
    setState(() {
      x = 250;
      y = 150;
      s = 0.6;
      _isDrawerOpened = true;
    });
  }

  void closeDrawer() {
    setState(() {
      x = 0;
      y = 0;
      s = 1;
      _isDrawerOpened = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      color: Colors.grey[900],
      curve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(x, y, 0)..scale(s),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      child: buildScaffold(),
    );
  }

  Widget buildScaffold() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildCustomAppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Curve Drawer Example"),
      ),
    );
  }

  AppBar buildCustomAppBar() {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        _isDrawerOpened ? Icons.clear : Icons.menu,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: _isDrawerOpened ? closeDrawer : openDrawer,
    ),
  );
}
```

**When you complete everthing you'll get result like this:**
[image: Default screen so drawer isn’t opened]
[image: Second screen so drawer was opened]